# Using custom image on google maps (prevent repeating in x direction)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to use my outline drawing on google maps. Because I need to add markers, polylines etc on it. 
I found this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image
But in this example, image repeats x direction. I don't know why. Is there any way to use image without repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the image from wrapping in the x direction, change this section of the code:

```
// repeat across x-axis
if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
  x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
}
```

To:

```
// don't repeat across x-axis
if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
  return null;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/eLzbw4xz/)

Comment: Fiddle is not working at all. The image is looping infinitly... probably back then with V2 but with V3.